# Difficulty with Kendo UI MVVM and an Associative Array

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am having a difficult time binding a view model using an "Associative Array" with Kendo UI's MVVM. I've attempted to amalgamate a demo together, but it is really hard to when I don't have even a half-working one to go off of. But this is the best I've managed... Here is my code, along with a jsBin to demonstrate. It just doesn't seem to like the idea of an associative array, and I'm not really certain how else to hook into it.

The reason for the associative array is because I am pulling a lot of details out of the database, but they'll need to be invoked in certain places by name. Rather than write a bunch of searching/sorting methods, an associative array is a lot simpler for this. But in a few places where I do need to just list the data outright, it is giving me a great deal of trouble.

## [jsBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/qaput/2/edit)

## Javascript

```
var viewModel = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
  Id: "test/id",
  Associative: new kendo.data.ObservableArray([])
});

var array = viewModel.get("Associative");

array["One"] = { Id: "id/one" };
array["Two"] = { Id: "id/two" };
array["Three"] = { Id: "id/three" };

kendo.bind('body', viewModel);
```

## HTML

```
<div data-bind="text: Id"></div>
<div data-template="display-associative-many" data-bind="source: Associative"></div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="display-associaite-many">
  <div>
    ${ data.Id }
  </div>
</script>
```

## Update

The data I need to bind to is stored in `RavenDB` as an `IDictionary<string, T>`, where `T` is a specific kind of object (it kind of varies at times, so I can't give you a concrete type - nor is it really relevant)

So it is stored in the database like ...

```
"Model" : {
   "ONE" : {
      "Id" : "id/one"
   },
   "TWO" : {
      "Id" : "id/two"
   },
   "THREE" : {
      "Id" : "id/three"
   }
}
```

Obviously there is more data than this, but this is all that is truly relevant at the moment.

While I **do** have the physical ability to change this, it is contrary to many other parts of the program. A lot of various places in the software work already on the premise of this being a dictionary. So I would *like* to avoid having to change all of that *if* possible. If that is truly, truly the only way to make this work at all, I will make the change.

What I could do though is do some mapping when it deserializes. My thought now is to assign the `key` to a new property, `Name`, and try to kendo bind to that. So the data would become, if my mental image is right ...

```
Associative: [
   "One" : {
      Name: "One",
      Id: "id/one"
   },
   "Two" : {
     Name: "Two",
     Id: "id/two"
   },
   "Three" : {
     Name: "Three",
     Id: "id/three"
   }
]
```

If I understand Kendo's `observable` system right, that would make it ...

```
kendo.data.ObservableArray([
   kendo.data.ObservableObject,
   kendo.data.ObservableObject,
   kendo.data.ObservableObject
])
```

And as I grasp it, that **should** be possible to model bind ... right?

## Update 2

Following my own idea, I have made a **somewhat** successful version work with this method... However, I am not entirely sure if this is safe or efficient. I am growing concerned with the performance. I'm still trying to find other ways to achieve this result.

### kendo template

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="display-items-many">
        # for(var key in data) { #
        #   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && data[key].hasOwnProperty("Id")) { #
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>#= data[key].Id #</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <code>#= data[key].Total #</code>
            </td>
        </tr>
        #   } #
        # } #
</script>
```

### html

```
<table class="table borderless table-hover table-condensed" data-bind="source: Associative  data-template="display-items-many">

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Your template name is wrong:

```
data-template="display-associaitive-many"
           id="display-associaite-many"
```

---

Second, JavaScript arrays don't work like that.

Plain JS (no Kendo involved):

```
var array = [];
array["One"] = { Id: "id/one" };
array["Two"] = { Id: "id/two" };
array["Three"] = { Id: "id/three" };

array; // prints "[]"
array.length; // prints 0
```

Associative arrays should be represented as objects http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/01/associative-arrays-in-javascript/ which you can then wrap into a Kendo `ObservableObject`. However, that means it isn't really an array with a length, so you can't bind it to a Kendo ListView.

Off the top on my head, the only way I can think of to represent that as a associative array (object) and still bind it to a ListView would be to bind your ListView to a function that then translates your object to an array. Tracking changes gets a little weird then though...

---

***In response to your comments and updates to the original post:***

I'm typing this off the top of my head, so my apologies if it doesn't work if you directly copy/paste it, but assuming you have a DataSource laoding the data, you could use the `schema.parse` method to turn your data into an actual array, like:

```
var _parseTheData = function (data) {
  var array = [];
  var item;
  for(var name in data) {
    item = data[name];
    item.Name = name;
    array.push(item);
  }
  return array;
};

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "http://wherever.com/theData"
    },
    schema: {
      parse: _parseTheData
    }
  }
});
```

The idea is that if your server returned the object:

```
{
   "ONE" : {
      "Id" : "id/one"
   },
   "TWO" : {
      "Id" : "id/two"
   },
   "THREE" : {
      "Id" : "id/three"
   }
}
```

Then the parse function would convert it to the Array:

```
[
   {
      "Id" : "id/one",
      "Name" : "ONE"
   },
   {
      "Id" : "id/two",
      "Name" : "TWO"
   },
   {
      "Id" : "id/three",
      "Name" : "THREE"
   }
]
```

Which you can then MVVM bind to a widget like normal. For example a ListLiew:

```
<div data-role="listview"
     data-bind="source: ds"
     data-template="item-template"></div>

<script id="item-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: Id"></div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that. My actual codebase has the correct spelling, I just needed to get a jsbin up to show the problem, so I overlooked it.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, the data is stored in `RavenDB` as an `IDictionary<string, T>` where `T` is a certain interface. I need to deserialize this and display it to the screen through kendo ui mvvm. While I can convert it to a normal array, this is not desired. However, I could assign the `key` to a new property `Name` on each item in the array. Would the dynamic change if I were to do that? Would that make it possible? If it was no longer dependent on the key name being the top level part?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details to try and explain this. I am sorry for the poor information at the start. I was not really all mentally here, yesterday

Comment: And if not, would it be possible using inline scripting inside of a template? Such as iterating every object within the observablearray?

Comment: I will explore this in a few moments, as I am just now getting into work. Thank you again for all of your help. I clearly have so far to go on learning javascript ...

Comment: I have prepared a document to demonstrate __exactly__ what and why I need to accomplish. I realize there is not a lot in it, but I am kind of a paranoid person, so I'd appreciate if it wasn't distributed without my knowledge. I plan to delete it once this is resolved. If you could look at this, it will explain more clearly what I am trying to do: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iJ42bIUUfcsLrcERIbewo4SoRJA1Crzsa8-YJvzW9us/pub?embedded=true

Comment: This may or may not help, but I have a blog post about binding to functions that return different data sets: http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2013/04/13/binding-kendo-listviews-to-the-result-of-a-function/ In your case, in the cases where you need to bind to a list of all skills, I would make a function on your ViewModel that returns a DataSource that iterates over the properties (skills) and returns them in a new array or DataSource.

Comment: I will read this as soon as I get the opportunity. Thank you very much for the followup. If I can be a burden and ask a question - am I trying to do something that is just horrible practice? The fact that this isn't supported out of the box concerns me. It isn't that I think kendo is letting me down, but when I run into something like this, it has me wondering if I'm just coding poorly.

Comment: Ok... so if I grasp what you're telling me here ... you say to leave my actual data untouched, but instead have a function whose sole purpose is to __return__ a normal array _from_ the associative array, and bind to that?

Comment: Wow, even if we can't solve this specific issue, your blog is amazing. It's got so much information related to the Kendo Framework!

Comment: Yeah, I would try to load your original data structure off the server then break it up into usable parts client side. That is just my take on it though. As with anything, it is hard to plan it all up front. You'll just need to try a few things and see what works best. Hopefully I've given you a few options to try. Good luck!

Comment: I'm trying what you suggested, but I'm getting a strange behavior. If I do it in a jsFiddle, it works fine, but when I run this in a local HTML file using the same javascript and css assets, the `Unwrapped` method gets called twice every page load : http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/nY9U4/