# Creating a new kendo binding for "associative arrays"

Tags: kendo-ui

I'll start off by stating that I don't know if this is possible at all, but I'm reading over the Kendo UI documentation and trying to figure out how to at least try it, but I'm running into a lot of difficulties with making a custom binding. This is a followup to another question I am still working on, which is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727545/difficulty-with-kendo-ui-mvvm-and-an-associative-array). If this is not an appropriate question, please kindly let me know, and I will close it or rephrase it. I'm just really lost and confused at this point.

As I understand it, based on what I've been told and tried, Kendo cannot bind to an *Associative Array* not because the data isn't good, but because it is an array of *objects*, each as a separate individual entity - under normal circumstances, an array would be a bit different and contain a **length** property, as well as some other functions in the *array* prototype that make iteration through it possible.

So I was trying to conjecture how to get around this. I succeeded in getting what I **think** was a workaround to function. I preface that with "think" because I'm still too inexperienced with Javascript to truly know the ramifications of doing it this way (performance, stability, etc)

Here is what I did;

### kendo template

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="display-items-many">
        # for(var key in data) { #
        #   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && data[key].hasOwnProperty("Id")) { #
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>#= data[key].Id #</strong>
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <code>#= data[key].Total #</code>
            </td>
        </tr>
        #   } #
        # } #
</script>
```

### html

```
<table class="table borderless table-hover table-condensed" data-bind="source: Associative  data-template="display-items-many">
                                
</table>
```

Now to me, immediately off hand, this gave me the illusion of functioning. So I got to thinking a bit more on how to fix this ...

I want to create a new `binding` called `repeat`. The goal of this binding is as follows;

> repeat the template for each instance of an object within the given root object that meets a given criteria

In my head, this would function like this;

```
<div data-template="repeater-sample" data-bind="repeat: Associative"></div>
 
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="repeater-sample">
   <div> ${ data.Id }</div>
</script>
```

And the *criteria* would be a property simply called *`_associationKey`*. So the following would, in theory, work.

```
$.ajax({
   // get data from server and such.
}).done(function(results){
   // simple reference to the 'associative array' for easier to read code
   var associative = results.AssociativeArray;

   // this is a trait that everything in the 'associative array' should have to match
   // this is purely, purely an example. Obviously you would use a more robust property
   var match = "Id"; 

   // go through the results and wire up the associative array objects
   for(var key in associative ) {
      if(associative.hasOwnProperty(key) && associative[key].hasOwnProperty(match)) {
         associative[key]._associationKey = 10; // obviously an example value
      }
   }

   // a watered down example implementation, obviously a real use would be more verbose
   viewModel = kendo.observable({
      // property = results.property
      // property = results.property
      associativeArray = associative
   });

   kendo.bind('body', viewModel);
});
```

So far this actually seems to work pretty well, but I have to hard code the logic in the template using inline scripting. That's kind of what I want to avoid.

## Problem

The big issue is that I'm vastly confused on telerik's documentation for custom bindings (available [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom)). I do have their examples to draw from, yes - but it's a bit confusing to me how it interacts with the object. I'll *try* to explain, but I'm so lost that it may be difficult.

This is what telerik gives for an example custom binding, and I've pruned it a bit for space concerns;

```
<script>
    kendo.data.binders.repeater = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
        init: function(element, bindings, options) {
            //call the base constructor
            kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, element, bindings, options);

            var that = this;
            // how do we interact with the data that was bound?
        }
    });
</script>
```

So essentially that's where I am lost. I'm having a big disconnect figuring out how to interact with the actual "associative array" that is bound using `data-bind="repeat: associativeArray"`

So ..

- I need to interact with the bound data (the entire 'associative array')
- I need to be able to tell it to render the target template for each instance that matches

## Further Updates

I have been digging through the kendo source code, and this is what I have so far - by taking the `source` binding as an example... but I'm still not getting the right results. Unfortunately this poses a few problems;

1. some of the functions are internal to kendo, I'm not sure how to get access to them without re-writing them. While I have the source and can do that, I'd prefer to make version agnostic code so that it can "plug in" to newer releases
2. I'm totally lost about what a lot of this does. I basically made a copy of the `source` binding and replaced it with my own syntax where possible, since the concept is fundamentally the same. *I cannot figure out where to do the **test** for qualification to be rendered*, if that makes sense.

I'm having a big logic disconnect here - there should ideally be **some** place where I can basically say ... *`If the current item that kendo is attempting to render in a template matches a criteria, render it. If not, pass it over`* and then another place where I tell it to iterate over every object in the 'associative array' so as to get to the point where I test it.

I feel just forcing a `for` loop in here will actually make this fire too many times, and I am getting pretty lost. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
kendo.data.binders.repeat = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    init: function(element, bindings, options) {
        kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, element, bindings, options);

        var source = this.bindings.repeat.get();

        if (source instanceof kendo.data.DataSource && options.autoBind !== false) {
            source.fetch();
        }
    },

    refresh: function(e) {
        var that = this,
            source = that.bindings.repeat.get();

        if (source instanceof kendo.data.ObservableArray|| source instanceof kendo.data.DataSource) {
            e = e || {};

            if (e.action == "add") {
                that.add(e.index, e.items);
            } else if (e.action == "remove") {
                that.remove(e.index, e.items);
            } else if (e.action != "itemchange") {
                that.render();
            }
        } else {
            that.render();
        }
    },

    container: function() {
        var element = this.element;

        if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "table") {
            if (!element.tBodies[0]) {
                element.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
            }
            element = element.tBodies[0];
        }

        return element;
    },

    template: function() {
        var options = this.options,
            template = options.template,
            nodeName = this.container().nodeName.toLowerCase();

        if (!template) {
            if (nodeName == "select") {
                if (options.valueField || options.textField) {
                    template = kendo.format('<option value="#:{0}#">#:{1}#</option>',
                        options.valueField || options.textField, options.textField || options.valueField);
                } else {
                    template = "<option>#:data#</option>";
                }
            } else if (nodeName == "tbody") {
                template = "<tr><td>#:data#</td></tr>";
            } else if (nodeName == "ul" || nodeName == "ol") {
                template = "<li>#:data#</li>";
            } else {
                template = "#:data#";
            }

            template = kendo.template(template);
        }

        return template;
    },

    add: function(index, items) {
        var element = this.container(),
            parents,
            idx,
            length,
            child,
            clone = element.cloneNode(false),
            reference = element.children[index];

        $(clone).html(kendo.render(this.template(), items));

        if (clone.children.length) {
            parents = this.bindings.repeat._parents();

            for (idx = 0, length = items.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                child = clone.children[0];
                element.insertBefore(child, reference || null);
                bindElement(child, items[idx], this.options.roles, [items[idx]].concat(parents));
            }
        }
    },

    remove: function(index, items) {
        var idx, element = this.container();

        for (idx = 0; idx < items.length; idx++) {
            var child = element.children[index];
            unbindElementTree(child);
            element.removeChild(child);
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        var source = this.bindings.repeat.get(),
            parents,
            idx,
            length,
            element = this.container(),
            template = this.template();

        if (source instanceof kendo.data.DataSource) {
            source = source.view();
        }

        if (!(source instanceof kendo.data.ObservableArray) && toString.call(source) !== "[object Array]") {
            source = [source];
        }

        if (this.bindings.template) {
            unbindElementChildren(element);

            $(element).html(this.bindings.template.render(source));

            if (element.children.length) {
                parents = this.bindings.repeat._parents();

                for (idx = 0, length = source.length; idx < length; idx++) {
                    bindElement(element.children[idx], source[idx], this.options.roles, [source[idx]].concat(parents));
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $(element).html(kendo.render(template, source));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I cannot say if it is possible and how far are you from achieving it, but I have a question that is (maybe) more important that is: what are you (finally) trying to achieve? i.e. what is the final purpose and what are you planning to (ultimately) do with this `Associative Array`? Maybe there is some solution using out-of-the-box code.

Comment: I have data stored in my database as an `IDictionary<string, object>` that I need to pull out and show. When deserialized, this equates to an associative array. I am attempting to see if I can bind to that without rebuilding the entire program again using different storage shapes.

Comment: Telerik technical support said that there was no out of the box solution, and that is when they suggested I make a binding.

Comment: See my proposed answer. Of course it has some limitations but I think that it might be worthwhile exploring this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose as a simpler solution transform transmitted `associative array` in an `array`. This is pretty simple and (for most cases) can solve your problem.

Lets say that you get the following associative array received from the server:

```
{
    "One" : { Name: "One", Id: "id/one" },
    "Two" : { Name: "Two", Id: "id/two" },
    "Three" : { Name: "Three", Id: "id/three" }
}
```

That is store in a variable called `input`. Transform it from `associative` to no associative is as easy as:

```
var output = [];
$.each(input, function(idx, elem) {
    elem.index = idx;
    output.push(elem);
});
```

Now, you have in `output` an equivalent array where I saved the index field into a field called `index` for each element of the associative array.

Now you can use out-of-the-box code for displaying the data received from the server.

See it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/AGfWc/

You can even use KendoUI `DataSource` for retrieving and transforming the data by using [`DataSource.schema.parse`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) method as:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: ...
    },
    schema : {
        parse: function (response) {
            var output = [];
            $.each(response, function(idx, elem) {
                elem.index = idx;
                output.push(elem);
            });
            return output;
        }
    }
});
```

and your model would be:

```
var viewModel = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    Id: "test/id",
    Associative: dataSource
});
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/AGfWc/1/

Comment: I'm not completely aversed to this, but there are other parts of the page where I need to be able to use the associative array aspect to call on specific indexes by name, and the process of doing that many "searches" would greatly impact performance.

Comment: However, thank you for it. I will read over it carefully and give it a try.

Comment: If you just need to access using associative array actually it is not a problem since due to how I copied `input` into `output` they both refer to the same object in memory. If you modify `input["One"].Name` you are actually modifying `output[0].Name`. The only question is that the HTML is not updated.

Comment: I'm unable to get back to a computer today, but will try it first thing tomorrow. If that is true, then yes, this will be perfect

Comment: So if I understand, you didn't change the actual objects, you instead created a copy?

Comment: Actually I do two things: 1. extend original element to include the `key` (just in case you need it); 2. build an array with references to the original objects (but extended). What I have in `output` is an array of references to `input` associative array `values` (not a `deep-copy`).

Comment: I apologize for being obnoxious, but will this have an impact on performance?

Comment: Just the opposite, since you do not allocate extra memory and you don't have to copy the object you actually save CPU cycles.

Comment: That is extremely interesting, and useful... okay, I am left with a bit of a quandry. You've given me an expert route to take, and I think I will definitely be using it - but I'm still curious about my original question. I'd like to write the binding just to learn how. So what is the appropriate thing to do here? Should I create a new question centered around what you answered here? Or should I change my existing question to match, and open a new question again for the binding issue?

Comment: Leave the question open and see if someone like Petur, Atanas, Lars... say something. I actually did not solve your question just say another way of overcoming the limitation.

Comment: Ok.. you said that I can still call them by their key, but I'm not seeing that. Take a look at this fiddle, am I still doing it wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/85LsK

Comment: You need some change (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/85LsK/4/). What I do is saving in the `viewModel` both the `array` and the `associative array`.

Comment: Ok. So I cannot interact with the original array in the looping, but only if it is copied. That's where I was afraid the performance hit would come into play ...

Comment: Still experimenting with your code, but I also updated the question with my latest progress on the binding.

Comment: Kendo UI team member here, the associative array is a very alien concept in JavaScript land. I would strongly advise rethinking your approach to something more idiomatic. A simple construct like `[ { key: "Foo", value: { ... } }, { key: "Bar", value: { ... } } ]` would work and spare you all the hassle.

Comment: @PetyoIvanov I am not saying I disagree with you, but I'm pretty lost about what you mean. It may help to understand my requirements better. Rather than try to make a ton of comments, would it be acceptable if I made a small google doc to describe my situation better? I'll prepare one up for you to look at.

Comment: @PetyoIvanov, and OnaBai - I have prepared a document to demonstrate __exactly__ what and why I need to accomplish. I realize there is not a lot in it, but I am kind of a paranoid person, so I'd appreciate if it wasn't distributed without my knowledge. I plan to delete it once this is resolved. If you could look at this, it will explain more clearly what I am trying to do: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iJ42bIUUfcsLrcERIbewo4SoRJA1Crzsa8-YJvzW9us/pub?embedded=true

Comment: I am really at a cross roads here, OnaBai and @Petyolvanov - The answers given here _are_ useful, and I'd like to give you credit for them, but I still haven't managed to solve my issue. I'm a bit nervous about doing a lot of transformation to the model because I fear that will lead to it becoming harder to send back to the database without more complication.

Comment: I guess the only option I have is to go with this for now, and keep trying to make a binding on the side. Thank you again for all of your help.